# Append to end of a line in a file

Tags: python, awk, sed, robotframework

So I have a keywords.robot file that starts as shown:

```
***SETTINGS***
library   rfgui.py   maximum_allowed_heartbeats_missed=2  DISPLAY=12
library   OperatingSystem
library   others.py
```

Now the file is to be run with Docker, but with the value of DISPLAY above to change to 0 e.g.

```
***SETTINGS***
library   rfgui.py   maximum_allowed_heartbeats_missed=2  DISPLAY=0
library   OperatingSystem
library   others.py
```

Is there a sed/awk command that I can use in the RUN part of my Dockerfile that can change this, so my Dockerfile RUN part may look something like:

```
RUN ["sh", "sed (...) > keywords.robot", "robot keywords.robot"]
```

Comment: Is there chance of any text after display keyword?

Comment: No @BarathVutukuri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU sed for `-E` and `-i` and `\s/\S` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`:

```
$ sed -Ei 's/(\sDISPLAY=)\S+/\10/' keywords.robot
$ cat keywords.robot
***SETTINGS***
library   rfgui.py   maximum_allowed_heartbeats_missed=2  DISPLAY=0
library   OperatingSystem
library   others.py
```

Comment: `sed -iE 's/( DISPLAY=)[[:digit:]]+/\10/' filename` would be better so that any other keyword present after that wouldn't get replaced.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri fair enough but I'll use `[^[:space:]]+` instead of `[[:digit:]]` as I don't know what values `DISPLAY` might hold, e.g. maybe `DISPLAY=27.2` or `DISPLAY="3"` or `DISPLAY=$default` are valid values.

Comment: Yeah that looks much better :)

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples. With `awk` you could try following way of substitution. This handles only 1 occurrence of DISPLAY=digits(.digits matching optionally here) you could change from `sub` to `gsub` for multiple occurrences substitution here.

```
awk '{sub(/DISPLAY=[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/,"DISPLAY="0)} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution*** with GNU `awk` using RS(record separator) option try:

```
awk -v RS='DISPLAY=[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' '{sub(/=[0-9]+/,"=0",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
***SETTINGS***
library   rfgui.py   maximum_allowed_heartbeats_missed=2  DISPLAY=12
library   OperatingSystem
library   others.py
```

then

```
awk '$NF~/^DISPLAY=/{$NF="DISPLAY=0"}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
***SETTINGS***
library rfgui.py maximum_allowed_heartbeats_missed=2 DISPLAY=0
library   OperatingSystem
library   others.py
```

Explanation: If last column content (`$NF`) starts with (`^`) `DISPLAY=` then set last column content to `DISPLAY=0`. For every line do `print`. Beware that this as-is would squeeze multiple spaces into single ones for line where modification take place. If you must have 3 spaces then change code to `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="   "}$NF~/^DISPLAY=/{$NF="DISPLAY=0"}{print}' file.txt`

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*